# Deploy Ember Application

Tags: ember.js, deployment, offline, application-cache

I have created an ember application (prior to the arrival of Ember CLI) which follows a file hierarchy as given below:

> Modules
>
> - Controllers
> - Views
> - Models
> - Routes
>
> App.js

I would like to know that is there any way to deploy these files by compiling as a single javascript and html file, like now we are doing in ember cli. Since my application is using offline APP Cache, I terribly need this feature to avoid save numberous files and downloading it from cache manifest file.

Comment: you could create a script (ant or OS specific) to concat files into one, possibly minify them prior to concatenating, and then reference that one from your html and cache files.

Comment: Ember cli is using broccoli as a build tool, you just need to integrate a build tool into your old project

Comment: You really should move your app over to ember-cli, so you don't waste time on writing your own build code. Would that be possible?

Comment: If he can't just setup gulp to concat minify and be done with it in 10min

Answer (score 0):

After some research I have decided to update application with Ember CLI. This seems to be the best option to build and deploy Ember Application.